# Repeating list elements in R

Tags: r

I have this list:

```
my_list <- list(V1 = c("A", "B", "C"), V2 = c("A", "B", "D"), V3 = c("A", "B", "E"), V4 = c("A", "B", "F"), V5 = c("A", "B", "G"))
```

I want to repeat each list element 4 times to get this list:

```
output <- list(V1 = c("A", "B", "C"), V2 = c("A", "B", "C"), V3 = c("A", "B", "C"), V4 = c("A", "B", "C"), V5 = c("A", "B", "D"), V6 = c("A", "B", "D"), V7 = c("A", "B", "D"), V8 = c("A", "B", "D"), V9 = c("A", "B", "E"), V10 = c("A", "B", "E"), V11 = c("A", "B", "E"), V12 = c("A", "B", "E"), V13 = c("A", "B", "F"), V14 = c("A", "B", "F"), V15 = c("A", "B", "F"), V16 = c("A", "B", "F"), V17 = c("A", "B", "G"), V18 = c("A", "B", "G"), V19 = c("A", "B", "G"), V20 = c("A", "B", "G"))
```

`unlist(rep(list(my_list), each = 4), recursive = F)` doesn't do the trick because it repeats the entire list 4 times instead of repeating each individual element 4 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you specify the same index multiple times, R respects the duplication:

```
letters[c(1, 1, 1)]
[1] "a" "a" "a"
```

Therefore all we need is a set of indices like `c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, ...)`. We can create exactly this with `rep`'s "each" argument, and then rename them with `names` and `paste0`:

```
my_list <- list(V1 = c("A", "B", "C"), V2 = c("A", "B", "D"), V3 = c("A", "B", "E"), V4 = c("A", "B", "F"), V5 = c("A", "B", "G"))

list_repeated <- my_list[rep(1:length(my_list), each = 4)]

names(list_repeated) <- paste0('V', 1:length(list_repeated))
```

Comment: could further simplify list_repeated to `list_repeated <- rep(my_list, each = 4)`